# What is Shopware 6 Administration system.config.spec.js file used for?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, shopware, shopware6

The Shopware 6 administration has the component `sw-system-config`, within the component, there is the file `vendor\shopware\administration\Resources\app\administration\src\module\sw-settings\component\sw-system-config\sw-system-config.spec.js` sw-system-config.spec.js. My question is what is this file used for and why is the codes different from other components.

I know my question is a little vague, I just need as much general information as possible as it concerns VueJS and JavaScript.

Below is the sw-system-config.spec.js code. How is it connected to the index.js file of the `sw-system-config` component. I could not find any link.

```js
/**
 * @package system-settings
 */
/* eslint-disable max-len */
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { kebabCase } from 'lodash';
import uuid from 'src/../test/_helper_/uuid';
import 'src/app/component/form/sw-custom-field-set-renderer';
import 'src/app/component/utils/sw-inherit-wrapper';
import 'src/app/component/form/sw-form-field-renderer';
import 'src/app/component/form/sw-field';
import 'src/app/component/base/sw-button';
import 'src/app/component/base/sw-label';
import 'src/app/component/form/sw-text-field';
import 'src/app/component/form/sw-switch-field';
import 'src/app/component/form/sw-number-field';
import 'src/app/component/form/sw-checkbox-field';
import 'src/app/component/form/field-base/sw-contextual-field';
import 'src/app/component/form/field-base/sw-block-field';
import 'src/app/component/form/field-base/sw-base-field';
import 'src/app/component/form/field-base/sw-field-error';
import 'src/app/component/base/sw-inheritance-switch';
import 'src/app/component/base/sw-icon';
import 'src/app/component/form/select/base/sw-single-select';
import 'src/app/component/form/select/base/sw-multi-select';
import 'src/app/component/form/select/entity/sw-entity-multi-select';
import 'src/app/component/form/select/entity/sw-entity-multi-id-select';
import 'src/app/component/form/select/base/sw-select-base';
import 'src/app/component/form/select/base/sw-select-result-list';
import 'src/app/component/form/select/base/sw-select-result';
import 'src/app/component/form/select/base/sw-select-selection-list';
import 'src/app/component/utils/sw-popover';
import 'src/app/component/base/sw-highlight-text';
import 'src/app/component/media/sw-media-field';
import 'src/app/component/media/sw-media-media-item';
import 'src/app/component/media/sw-media-base-item';
import 'src/app/component/media/sw-media-preview-v2';
import 'src/app/filter/media-name.filter';
import 'src/module/sw-settings/component/sw-system-config';
import 'src/app/component/base/sw-card';
import 'src/app/component/structure/sw-sales-channel-switch';
import 'src/app/component/form/select/entity/sw-entity-single-select';
import 'src/app/component/form/sw-textarea-field';
import 'src/app/component/form/sw-url-field';
import 'src/app/component/form/sw-password-field';
import 'src/app/filter/unicode-uri';

/** @type Wrapper */
let wrapper;

async function createWrapper(defaultValues = {}) {
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.directive('tooltip', {});
    localVue.directive('popover', {});
    localVue.filter('mediaName', Shopware.Filter.getByName('mediaName'));
    localVue.filter('unicodeUri', Shopware.Filter.getByName('unicodeUri'));

    return shallowMount(await Shopware.Component.build('sw-system-config'), {
        localVue,
        propsData: {
            salesChannelSwitchable: true,
            domain: 'ConfigRenderer.config'
        },
        stubs: {
            'sw-form-field-renderer': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-form-field-renderer'),
            'sw-card': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-card'),
            'sw-ignore-class': true,
            'sw-sales-channel-switch': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-sales-channel-switch'),
            'sw-entity-single-select': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-entity-single-select'),
            'sw-button': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-button'),
            'sw-label': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-label'),
            'sw-inherit-wrapper': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-inherit-wrapper'),
            'sw-inheritance-switch': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-inheritance-switch'),
            'sw-field': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-field'),
            'sw-text-field': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-text-field'),
            'sw-password-field': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-password-field'),
            'sw-textarea-field': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-textarea-field'),
            'sw-contextual-field': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-contextual-field'),
            'sw-switch-field': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-switch-field'),
            'sw-number-field': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-number-field'),
            'sw-checkbox-field': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-checkbox-field'),
            'sw-block-field': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-block-field'),
            'sw-base-field': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-base-field'),
            'sw-field-error': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-field-error'),
            'sw-icon': {
                template: '<div class="sw-icon" @click="$emit(\'click\')"></div>'
            },
            'sw-single-select': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-single-select'),
            'sw-multi-select': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-multi-select'),
            'sw-entity-multi-select': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-entity-multi-select'),
            'sw-entity-multi-id-select': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-entity-multi-id-select'),
            'sw-select-base': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-select-base'),
            'sw-select-result-list': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-select-result-list'),
            'sw-select-result': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-select-result'),
            'sw-select-selection-list': await Shopware.Component.build('sw-select-selection-list'),
.
.
.
.
.
```